# ElasticSearch-Haystack: Spanish Tokenizer "Fails"

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using:

- Haystack        - 2.1.0
- ElasticSearch   - 0.90.3
- pyelasticsearch - 0.6

I've configured a custom backend to change default Elasticsearch settings and use Spanish analyzer.

I'm using this settings for Elasticsearch:

```
"settings" : {

        "index": {
            "uuid": "IPwcMthwRpSJzpjtarc9eQ",
            "analysis": {
               "analyzer": {
                  "default": {
                     "filter": ["standard", "lowercase", "asciifolding", ],
                     "tokenizer": "standard"
                  }
               }
            },
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "number_of_shards": "10",
        }
    },
    "analyzer": {
            "spanish": {
              "tokenizer":  "standard",
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "spanish_stop",
                "spanish_keywords",
                "spanish_stemmer"
              ]
            }
    }
```

I read this settings in some answer here. When I apply this settings to ElasticSearch and reindex my models I get a behaviour that I'm not sure I understand.

I have some objects with names like "Ciencias" and others like "Ciéncies" When I do a search like "ciencias" I receive objects with names like "Ciencias" and "Ciéncies", and the same happens when I search for "ciencies" or "ciéncies".

---

I want ElasticSearch to ignore accents, that's why I'm using asciifolding, and using spanish tokenizer because most of text is in spanish. I don't understand why using different words like "cienciAs" and "cienciEs" receive same results.

Why is this happening ? Is because a default ngram analyzer that is splitting the words ?

Why searching for "cienciAs" I get object with name like "ciénciEs" as results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I removed the Spanish analyzer and everything began to work as expected.

Now I'm using only `Asciifolding` and `Lowercase` filters and accents and ñ's are being indexed well, and I don't have the issue with `ciencias` and `ciencies`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the stemmer is doing its job. If you want to find out what happens while tokenising or stemming, install the [inquisitor plugin](https://github.com/polyfractal/elasticsearch-inquisitor) and go to the Analyzers tab (see [here](https://github.com/polyfractal/elasticsearch-inquisitor#analyzer-testing))

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've never used Inquisitor plugin and seems really helpfull! In the analyzer tab the only analyzer that split the words "ciencias" or "ciéncies" is `Snowball` analyzer, but It shouldn't be using that analyzer

Comment: A bit unrelated to your original question, but check out the icu-analysis plugin, it can do collation correctly in all kind of languages, you are not limited using asciifolding

Comment: Sorry for my english as you can supose it's not my first language. I disabled the stemmer and still getting same results, I'm looking for better configurations for the analyzer.